# Dismissing UIImagePickerController resets UITabBarController to 0 index - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have 4 tabs in my `UITabBarController` and I present `UIImagePickerController` from the 4th ViewController in my tabBar. (All the tabs viewControllers are embedded in `UINavigationController`)

When my `UIImagePickerController` is dismissing from my 4th tab, whether after selecting an image or just cancelling the picker, it takes me back to my first tab (0 index).

It should stay to my 4th tab viewController. Why is this happening? I have searched all in the code and there's no where I have mentioned `tabBarController.setSelectedIndex = 0;`

This is my code to present the `UIImagePickerController` and dismiss it:

```
- (void)takeNewPhotoFromCamera
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        controller.allowsEditing = NO;
        //controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];

    }
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried presenting the picker from the tabbarcontroller rather than the embedded view controller?

Comment: Where do you call `(void)takeNewPhotoFromCamera` method ?
From `tabBarController` or inside `yourViewController`

Comment: @BJHStudios Yes. Tried presenting the picker from tabBarController and same issue after dismissal.

Comment: @matiboo I call it inside my `viewController` which is connected to 4th tab in my `tabBarController`

Comment: Sorry, but i have no idea why this happened with your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution by setting the image picker's `modalPresentationStyle` to `OverCurrentContext` :

```
UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
controller.allowsEditing = NO;
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext; //This is the magical line
[self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
```